# How would you implement the MSN "eventlist scroller" in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, controls, expression-blend

Yes, this might be subjective.  I hope it is not closed.  It will be an interesting topic.  On MSN's web site there is a control that I understand is called an EventList Scroller.  There are little left and right buttons that a user can click on that changes the content of images above the little buttons.  The images woosh to the left or the right depending on what the user clicks on.  This is a fun and entertaining way to display content.

I am wondering what to start with to make such a control.

Expression Studio has a ScrollViewer. I wonder if you can make it scroll horizontally instead of vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just adapt code such as this?

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/09/18/create-an-automatic-scrollable-image-slider-in-silverlight.aspx